# Is there any nicer way to write successive "or" statements in Python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Simple question to which I can't find any "nice" answer by myself:

Let's say I have the following condition:

```
if 'foo' in mystring or 'bar' in mystring or 'hello' in mystring:
    # Do something
    pass
```

Where the number of `or` statement can be quite longer depending on the situation.

Is there a "nicer" (more Pythonic) way of writing this, without sacrificing performance ?

If thought of using `any()` but it takes a list of boolean-like elements, so I would have to build that list first (giving-up short circuit evaluation in the process), so I guess it's less efficient.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A way could be

```
if any(s in mystring for s in ('foo', 'bar', 'hello')):
    pass
```

The thing you iterate over is a tuple, which is built upon compilation of the function, so it shouldn't be inferior to your original version.

If you fear that the tuple will become too long, you could do

```
def mystringlist():
    yield 'foo'
    yield 'bar'
    yield 'hello'
if any(s in mystring for s in mystringlist()):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't that technique prevents short-circuit optimization ?

Comment: It's a generator, not a list.

Comment: Nope. `(s in mystring for s in 'foo', 'bar', 'hello')` is a generator expression, which means it's not calculated instantly as a whole, only on-demand. `any()` stops the iteration upon seeing first true value, so the rest won't ever be checked. Read up on generator expressions.

Comment: @ereOn, `any` short circuits. Why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: But `'foo', 'bar', 'hello'` is a tuple which gets built immediately.

Comment: @gnibbler: I haven't said `any` doesn't short circuit. I feared the **list construction** would not. But since it's actually a generator, that changes everything.

Comment: OTOH, you wouldn't have short-circuiting if you did `any([s in mystring for s in ... ])`. The `[]` list comprehensions always create a whole list; `any()` wouldn't iterate throught it all but it would still be evaluated before the `any` call.

Comment: @Kos: That, I did not know. Very interesting to read. Thanks to you and to the answer's author !

Comment: Edit: I've added a pair of parentheses in the tuple inside generator expression (I forget about them too all the time!)

Comment: @glglgl I don't think it actually makes a difference whether the substrings are stored individually or together as a tuple. Your generator won't actually be all that efficient spacewise because the values are still stored explicitly rather than calculated as you go along.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a job for a regex.

```
import re

if re.search("(foo|bar|hello)", mystring):
    # Do something
    pass
```

It should be faster, too. Especially if you compile the regex ahead of time.

If you're generating the regular expression automatically, you could use `re.escape()` to make sure no special characters break your regex. For example, if `words` is a list of strings you wish to search for, you could generate your pattern like this:

```
pattern = "(%s)" % ("|".join(re.escape(word) for word in words), )
```

You should also note that if you have `m` words and your string has `n` characters, your original code has `O(n*m)` complexity, while the regular expression has `O(n)` complexity. Even though Python regexs are not really theoretical comp-sci regular expressions, and are not *always* `O(n)` complexity, in this simple case they are.

Comment: But you have to be careful if any of the "words" you are looking for contain special regex characters

Comment: @gnibbler: True. Conversely, you might be able to write less code by using pattern matching. If you're doing something like auto-generating the regex, you could use `re.escape()`.

Comment: Indeed you can, you should add that to your answer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My real case scenario is less compatible with this technique (but you could obviously not guess). Upvoted for fairness because the answer is valid and could help somebody.

Comment: Indeed faster! http://ideone.com/MLgCU Probably because the regex only needs to traverse the string once.

Comment: Also +1 for `re.escape()`, didn't know that

Comment: @gnibbler: Added. Also added a note about complexity.

Comment: @ereOn: Out of curiosity, what exactly is the problem? I can't think of anything major... Well, if you're dealing with strings anyway.

Comment: @Kos: Actually, looking at your code, I see you tested for the "easy case", where the `any` short-circuits right away. For a more interesting example, try this one where the correct substring is "hello": http://ideone.com/VljQ2

Comment: @cha0site: My real case scenario involves a file that must be modified at times by people that don't know Python. While your solution is obviously faster, they probably thing it is less maintainable to change a big string used in a regex than to add/remove/update a line in a list declaration. Now I know I could use the `"""` notation to split the declaration across several lines, but I asked them and they don't seem to like it. If it were up to me only, I would have used your solution, hence the upvote.

Comment: @ereOn: You could build the regex dynamically from a list - I even showed you how to do it =)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are processing word-by-word against `mystring`, surely mystring can be used as a set. Then just take the intersection between the set containing the words in `mystring` and the target groups of words:

```
In [370]: mystring=set(['foobar','barfoo','foo'])

In [371]: mystring.intersection(set(['foo', 'bar', 'hello']))
Out[371]: set(['foo'])
```

Your logical 'or' is the members of the intersection of the two sets.

Using a set is also faster. Here are relative timing vs a generator and regular expression:

```
f1:  generator to test against large string 
f2:  re to test against large string 
f3:  set intersection of two sets of words 

    rate/sec      f2     f1     f3
f2   101,333      -- -95.0% -95.5%
f1 2,026,329 1899.7%     -- -10.1%
f3 2,253,539 2123.9%  11.2%     --
```

So a generator and the `in` operation is 19x faster than a regular expression and a set intersection is 21x faster than a regex and 11% faster than a generator.

Here is the code that generated the timing:

```
import re

with open('/usr/share/dict/words','r') as fin:
     set_words={word.strip() for word in fin}

s_words=' '.join(set_words)
target=set(['bar','foo','hello'])
target_re = re.compile("(%s)" % ("|".join(re.escape(word) for word in target), ))

gen_target=(word for word in ('bar','foo','hello'))

def f1():
    """ generator to test against large string """        
    if any(s in s_words for s in gen_target):
        return True

def f2():
    """ re to test against large string """
    if re.search(target_re, s_words):
        return True

def f3():
    """ set intersection of two sets of words """
    if target.intersection(set_words):
        return True

funcs=[f1,f2,f3]
legend(funcs)
cmpthese(funcs)
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? The only difference is that you use a `set` instead of a `tuple`, otherwise it's exactly the same.

Comment: @cha0site: The accepted answer also proposes a function for a large list. I think a set is better way to so the same. This is also proposing two sets -- without the use of `any`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a known list of items to check against, you could also write it as

```
if mystring in ['foo', 'bar', 'hello']:
```

You may not get the benefits of ensuring the comparison order (I don't think Python is required to check the list elements left-to-right) but that's only a problem if you know that 'foo' is way more likely than 'bar'.

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing.  The condition in the question would also be true when `mystring = 'hello world'`.  This one would not.

Comment: Good point, thanks - as you say, not quite the same thing, and perhaps not a good fit to the specific problem.